# Implicit type conversion in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I am porting a C++ program to C#. I just started to learn C#.

In C++, if I define a constructor with string parameter

```
class ProgramOption { public: ProgramOptions(const char* s=0); };
```

Then I can use string parameter in the place of ProgramOptions, such as

```
int myfucn(ProgramOption po);
myfunc("s=20;");
```

I can also use it as default argument, such as,

```
int myfunc(ProgramOption po=ProgramOption());
```

Unfortunately in C#, even I have

```
class ProgramOption { public ProgramOptions(const char* s=0) {...} }
```

I found that I can't use it as default argument,

```
int myfunc(ProgramOption po=new ProgramOption());
```

and I can't pass string literal without explicit conversion, such as

```
myfunc("s=20");
```

Is this simply impossible in C# or I can implement some method to make it happen? Thanks

Comment: Anything wrong with using `int myfunc(new ProgramOption());`?

Comment: I'm sure you already know this but C# and C++, while both may even be considered "C Heritage" - they are very different. If you are interested in learning the language fully, try to learn C# with new examples instead of just by porting what you already know. Just my $0.02!

Comment: By the way, in C# `"s=20"` is not a `char*` - you will have to use `string`, even if you are in C++ you could use `std::string` - if you were in C you would probably stick to `char*`, though.

Answer (score 6):

You would need to define an implicit cast operator. Something like this:

```
class ProgramOption
{
    //...

    public ProgramOptions(string str = null)
    {
        //...
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        {
            /* store or parse str */
            //...
        }
    }

    //...

    public static implicit operator ProgramOptions(string str)
    {
        return new ProgramOptions(str);
    }
}
```

---

Then would allow you to have your function like this:

```
int myfunc(ProgramOption po = null)
{
    po = po ?? new ProgramOptions(); //default value
    //...
}
```

And call it like this:

```
myfunc("some text");
```

Comment: To add on this, you can get the default argument thing by setting the default to `null`, then testing with `po = po ?? new ProgramOptions();`

Comment: It is used extensively in `System.Xml.Linq` classes where you can pass a `string` instead of a `XName`.

Answer (score 1):

From [Does C# have default parameters?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/85556.aspx)

> In languages such as C++, a default value can be included as part of the method declaration:
>   void Process(Employee employee, bool bonus = false)
>   ...
>   C# doesn't have this feature.

but also

> Update:
>   Named and optional (default) parameters are available starting from C# 4.0.

[Named and Optional Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739%28VS.100%29.aspx)

> Visual C# 2010 introduces named and optional arguments. ... Optional arguments enable you to omit arguments for some parameters.

and later

> **Optional Arguments**
>   - a constant expression;
>   - an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;
>   - an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.